# Why should I use OAuth,SAML,Identity Server

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, saml, identityserver4

We have many web applications and want to integrate SSO.What is the benefit of using OAuth,SAML,Identity Server. What is different from making a custom webapi that produce token and authenticate user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 protocols that you can use for SSO.

WS-Fed, SAML 2.0, OpenID Connect / OAuth 2.0.

The first 2 are the "old" way and are more for enterprise.

The later is the "new" way and is used by modern applications / mobile etc.

Unless there is good reason not to, use OpenID Connect / OAuth 2.0.

Microsoft has OWIN NuGet packages for these for the client.

Whatever you use, do **not** roll your own. You are pretty much guaranteed to get security wrong.

IdentityServer is an open-source implementation of these protocols. It supports OpenID Connect / OAuth 2.0 OOTB and the other 2 via add-ons.

I've used it extensively - it's definitely a good choice.

Comment: if I use my own way, what kind of security problems I will face with?

Comment: Pretty much everything. You have to think about passwords, hashing, salting, encryption, protocols etc. And don't underestimate the time it takes to roll your own.